# Android / iOS мессенжер

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, клиент-сервер, messenger

Решил разработать мобильный мессенжер, типа VK, Telegram, Viber, WhatsApp. Так вот с клиентской (мобильной) частью все ясно и понятно. Какая технология наиболее популярная для реализации серверной части? Я думаю, что ASP.NET MVC подойдет, но может есть лучший вариант. Какой будет сервер точно еще не знаю, поэтому принимаю любые варианты.

Comment: Серьезный вопрос)
на самом деле хотелось бы посмотреть как такой проект будет делаться, он в open source?

Comment: Пока еще нет, но как начну реализацию, сразу скину ссылку.

Answer (score 2):

Первое, на что стоит обратить внимание - это XMPP. (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP, [полезно](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-xmppintro/))

VK до недавних пор использовал XMPP. WhatsApp расширил и модифицировал этот протокол.

**Плюсы:**

- открытый и расширяемый
- большое community (почти 20 лет в деле)
- огромное количество готовых библиотек, серверов и клиентов в OpenSource

**Минусы:**

- XML, как формат данных, морально устарел
- С вероятностью 99% придется костылить ([link](https://habrahabr.ru/post/261517/))

Но в общем и целом, даже в 2017 году XMPP в лидерах. По серверной части, советую обратить внимание на открытое решение - [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/). Реализован на Java, поддерживается и развивается. Всё, что может понадобиться - в нем есть. Более того, от тех же разработчиков и библиотека для клиентской части - [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp). (то что надо для Android-клиента)